# Does exchanging rows and columns change the value of a functional determinant by a sign?

Tags: functional-analysis, determinant

Suppose we have an operator (with some suitable boundary conditions) like

\begin{equation}
O =\begin{pmatrix}
a(t) & \frac{d}{dt} +b(t) \\ \frac{d}{dt}+ b(t) & c(t)
\end{pmatrix}
\end{equation}

Would an exchange of rows or columns change the value of the functional determinant in the same way it would change the value of a regular determinant?

Comment: Answer : yes, of course.